# VNC Send Apple Mac Cmd-Tab (Switch App) From Windows to OSX

Tags: mac, vnc

How can I send a cmd + tab message to a Mac from a windows client?

I'm using Ultra VNC.

Comment: Which VNC client are you using?

Comment: Sorry, missed that vital bit, I've updated the question.